# HTTP response headers valid with no Transfer-Encoding and Content-Length?

Tags: http, http-headers

Is a HTTP response Header (like the one below) legal even if if does not contain Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding?

```
- Http: Response, HTTP/1.1, Status: Ok, URL: /AAA/B.json
  ProtocolVersion: HTTP/1.1
  StatusCode: 200, Ok
  Reason: OK
  Expires:  Fri, 05 Oct 2012 01:41:30 GMT
  Date:  Fri, 05 Oct 2012 01:40:46 GMT
  Vary:  Accept-Encoding
  Accept-Ranges:  bytes
  Cache-Control:  public, max-age=43
  Server:  Noelios-Restlet-Engine/1.1.10
  ContentType:  application/json;charset=UTF-8
  ContentEncoding:  gzip
  Connection:  close
  X-Served-By:  85.111
  HeaderEnd: CRLF
```

I expected to see either Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding, but none of them exist.

I read the HTTP-RFC but am still unsure.

@CodeCaster, I did read RFC section 4.4, but am still not clear, as you can see, the response header is used to return a json stream, so:

- section 4.4, rule 1 defines MUST NOT include a message-body, does not seem to apply to my case.
- section 4.4, rule 4, not sure about this, but since I do not see "multipart/byteranges" in the response header - does it mean this rule is not applicable for me?
- section 4.4 rule 5, this is mostly unclear to me since the header actual contain "Connection : close", is it related?

So, any further comments?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is valid. There are five ways to determine the message length:

> [RFC 2616 Section 4.4. Message Length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4):
>
> The transfer-length of a message is the length of the message-body as
> it appears in the message; that is, after any transfer-codings have
> been applied. When a message-body is included with a message, the
> transfer-length of that body is determined by one of the following
> (in order of precedence):
>
> 1. Any response message which "MUST NOT" include a message-body (such
>    as the 1xx, 204, and 304 responses and any response to a HEAD
>    request) is always terminated by the first empty line after the
>    header fields, regardless of the entity-header fields present in
>    the message.
> 2. If a Transfer-Encoding header field (section 14.41) is present and
>    has any value other than "identity", then the transfer-length is
>    defined by use of the "chunked" transfer-coding (section 3.6),
>    unless the message is terminated by closing the connection.
> 3. If a Content-Length header field (section 14.13) is present, its
>    decimal value in OCTETs represents both the entity-length and the
>    transfer-length. The Content-Length header field MUST NOT be sent
>    if these two lengths are different (i.e., if a Transfer-Encoding
>    header field is present). If a message is received with both a
>    Transfer-Encoding header field and a Content-Length header field,
>    the latter MUST be ignored.
> 4. If the message uses the media type "multipart/byteranges", and the
>    transfer-length is not otherwise specified, then this self-
>    delimiting media type defines the transfer-length. This media type
>    [M]UST NOT be used unless the sender knows that the recipient can parse
>    it; the presence in a request of a Range header with multiple byte-
>    range specifiers from a 1.1 client implies that the client can parse
>    multipart/byteranges responses.
>
> > A range header might be forwarded by a 1.0 proxy that does not
> > understand multipart/byteranges; in this case the server MUST
> > delimit the message using methods defined in items 1,3 or 5 of
> > this section.
>
> 5. By the server closing the connection. (Closing the connection
>    cannot be used to indicate the end of a request body, since that
>    would leave no possibility for the server to send back a response.)

Comment: I did read RFC section 4.4, but am still not clear, as you can see, the response header is used to return a json stream, so:

 - section 4.4, rule 1 defines MUST NOT include a message-body, does not seem to apply to my case.
 - section 4.4, rule 4, not sure about this, but since I do not see "multipart/byteranges" in the response header - does it mean this rule is not applicable for me?
 - section 4.4 rule 5, this is mostly unclear to me since the header actual contain "Connection : close", is it related?

So, any further comments? thanks!

Comment: @user1721757 rule 1 is only applicable to the mentioned status codes. You receive a 200 and there is a `Connection: close` header, so your client should keep reading until the server closes the connection.

Comment: Yeah, if you use pfsense with snort. It will get blocked. https://www.snort.org/rule_docs/120-3